# Random number- same number on every run different number for each row

Tags: python, pandas

i want the following function will return a different number for each row in a data frame but the same number every time the function runs.

thanks.

```
def inc14(p):
if p==1:
    return random.randint(1,2000)
elif p==2:
    return random.randint(2001,3000)
elif p==3:
    return random.randint(3001,4000)
elif p==4:
    return random.randint(4001,5000)
elif p==5:
    return random.randint(5001,7000)
elif p==6:
    return random.randint(7001,9000)
elif p==7:
    return random.randint(9001,12000)
elif p==8:
    return random.randint(12001,15000)
elif p==9:
    return random.randint(15001,20000)
elif p==10:
    return random.randint(20001,40000)
elif p==11:
    return 0.01
else:
    return np.NaN

data['inc_cont14']=data['inc14'].apply(inc14)
```

Comment: How does you data look like? How many rows do you have? are those intervals important or you just need random numbers that will be the same each time?

Comment: how do you mean the same number every time the function is called?

Comment: If you need repeatable random numbers, look into [seeding](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.seed) the random number generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Defined ranges doesn't matter:**

Here a running example if the defined ranges doesn't matter, if they matter see below:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

random.seed(42) # Seed is here to always produce the same numbers

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  #create a dummy dataframe

# The dataframe has 4 rows. So we need 4 random numbers.
# If we want to generate 4 random numbers, without duplicates we can use random.sample
# In this example we sample 4 random number in the range of 0-399
range_multiplier = 100
df['Random'] = random.sample(range(len(df.index)*range_multiplier), len(df.index))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age  Random
0    Tom   20     327
1   nick   21      57
2  krish   19      12
3   jack   18     379
```

You can run the same code and will get the same random number than I have if you use the same seed than I used.

**Defined ranges matter:**

And in case you need this ranges here the new function which is a lot shorter, but you have to prepare all the numbers.:

```
random.seed(42) # Seed is here to always produce the same numbers

# for all p(1-10) and their ranges (1-2000, 2001-3000, 3001-4000,...) 
# we generate a dictionary with p as the key 
# and as value a list of all numbers in the defined range
# without duplicates with random.sample
p_numbers = {
    1: random.sample(range(1, 2001), 2000),
    2: random.sample(range(2001, 3001), 1000),
    ...
    10: random.sample(range(20001,40001), 20000)
}

def inc14(p,p_numbers):
    if p >= 1 and p<=10:
        # take the first element of the number and remove it
        # from the list (to avoid taking it again)
        return p_numbers[p].pop(0) 
    elif p == 11:
        return 0.01
    else:
        return np.nan

data['inc_cont14']=data['inc14'].apply(inc14,p_numbers)
```

We need the seed again to not get any duplicates.

We create a dictionary with the available numbers for their p. if p is between 1 and 10 we take the number from the dictionary and remove it from there to not get it twice.

Comment: Thanks
what the 42 in the seed refers to?

Comment: @yona you can take any number you want. I like the number 42 that's all.

Comment: @yona and if it helped you please mark the post as accepted so that people that have a similar problem later on can see that it is solved and how.

Answer (score 1):

random is only random as the seed changes each time. If you set the seed you will get the same result each time since yous tart from the same seed.

```py
import random


def inc14(p):
    random.seed(10)
    if p == 1:
        return random.randint(1, 2000)
    elif p == 2:
        return random.randint(2001, 3000)
    elif p == 3:
        return random.randint(3001, 4000)
    elif p == 4:
        return random.randint(4001, 5000)
    elif p == 5:
        return random.randint(5001, 7000)
    elif p == 6:
        return random.randint(7001, 9000)
    elif p == 7:
        return random.randint(9001, 12000)
    elif p == 8:
        return random.randint(12001, 15000)
    elif p == 9:
        return random.randint(15001, 20000)
    elif p == 10:
        return random.randint(20001, 40000)
    elif p == 11:
        return 0.01
    else:
        return None
        return np.NaN


for _  in range(10):
    print(inc14(4), inc14(7))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
4586 11341
```